# ¿Como trasponer columna y contar frecuencias de una dataframe en python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Busco realizar una matriz a partir de una dataframe.
Tengo una dataframe con los elementos: "Tiendas" y "Productos".
Estoy intentando contar la frecuenca de los productos por cada tienda, busco que el index sean los tiendas, y el nombre de los productos sean encabezados de columnas y que las filas contengas el conteo de los productos por cada tienda.

Espero haberme dado a entender

La dataframe es como la que muestro a continuación:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Producto = ["jabon", "detergente", "yogurt", "yogurt", "jabon", "yogurt", "yogurt", "jabon", "jabon", "detergente"]
Tienda = ["sucursal_1", "sucursal_2", "sucursal_3","sucursal_1", "sucursal_2", "sucursal_3","sucursal_1", "sucursal_2", "sucursal_3", "sucursal_3" ]
df= pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Tienda, Producto)), columns = ["Tienda", "Producto"])
print(df)
```

he intentado con la función "groupby" de pandas y con la función pivot pero aùn no logro resolverlo.

Cabe destacar que mi objetivo final es realizar un heatmap.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una solución, espero que pueda servirle a alguien más.
Agregué una nueva columna a la dataframe con valores del 1 al 10, los que fueron reemplazados por el conteo de los "Productos" con la función

```
#Creando una matriz de datos
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

    Producto = ["jabon", "detergente", "yogurt", "yogurt", "jabon", "yogurt", "yogurt", "jabon", "jabon", "detergente"]
Tienda = ["sucursal_1", "sucursal_2", "sucursal_3","sucursal_1", "sucursal_2", "sucursal_3","sucursal_1", "sucursal_2", "sucursal_3", "sucursal_3" ]
Conteo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df= pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Tienda, Producto, Conteo)), columns = ["Tienda", "Producto", "Conteo"])
print(df)

df1= df.pivot_table(values = "Conteo", index= "Tienda", columns = "Producto", aggfunc=lambda Conteo: len(Conteo.unique()))

# reemplazar NAs a cero
df1 = df1.fillna(0)

import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(df1)
```